# PHP Mail just suddenly stop working

Tags: php, email

It's been a while that i have used the php mail function in the contact form of my site to send out emails. Recently, I have found out that it just stop working. When i send an inquiry in my contact form, it says successfully sent but  none of the test i did came into my inbox..

Does anyone facing the same issue here? How can i possibly fix this?

I checked the MX entry in cpanel and  the data is correct. I want to try SMTP but i dont have access information.

ANy help on this matter?

Additional Information i have found out:
Web Server is hosted in one of the hosting company.
Mail server is hosted in google.

Where is probably is the problem here?

Comment: Have you tried sending to other addresses (Gmail / Yahoo / etc)? Have you tried connecting directly to your SMTP using telnet to see if there's a problem when you try to connect?

Comment: http://postmarkapp.com/ is a great solution for sending mail with a script. They have a nice PHP wrapper that is easy to use.

Comment: Do what andrewsi suggested, also log in to the WHM interface and check your mail queue.

Comment: @andrewsi: yes, i have tried it. About SMTP and telnet, i really dont have any idea about it. I dont even know the smtp username and password. I asked the hosting support but they cant provide either.

Comment: Do you have SSH access to the server, or is it all done through interfaces?

Comment: @kyle: I don't see a mail que menu in my cpanel.

Comment: @user1149244 If you can log onto the server, and type `telnet <mailserver> 25`, and see what happens. If it gives you an error message, that should explain what the problem is. Otherwise, just close the connection, and the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @user1149244 - One other thing I'd suggest is writing a very basic PHP page that sends a simple email to your address - don't add any extra headers, formatting or anything. Just a basic Hello World to your email address. See if that gets to you.

Comment: @andrewsi: I got this result http://pastebin.com/QTqbDPzN . Whats possibly the reason that it is not connecting?

Comment: @user1149244 - I've no idea what the error might be, but it does look like the mailserver isn't accessible from the webserver any longer. You might need to contact your hosting support, and hope they can help this time.

Comment: The hosting support we have is very bad.

Comment: I also had the exact same problem with cPanel. :(

Comment: @D.Pardal see the accepted answer if it will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, the issue here is that mail exim of the hosting server was broken. So, hosting support had to update it and that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the problem is with your hosting provider, which "figured out" that your form was generating a lot of traffic and it was blocked.

Comment: I contacted our hosting provider and they are not giving us a good support at all. They just told us to check the mail settings and the PHP mail function but I dont get any error message at all from the mail.

Comment: If has worked so far, and now it stopped suddenly, then the problem must be the server you're hosting your form. Have you tried using it on another host to test? How often were you using that form?

Answer (score 1):

Or something has gone wrong. Look at `/var/log/mail.*` for issue.

Comment: I run the command but it isn't successful at all. root@mydomain [~]# cd /var/log/mail.*
-bash: cd: /var/log/mail.*: No such file or directory

Comment: I mean some files, do `ls /var/log/mail.*`, you'll see  log files, read them.

Comment: got the following error when doing that command. ls /var/log/mail.*
/bin/ls: /var/log/mail.*: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

Are you properly validating what the mail() function returns?

It might be a good idea to check your error_log too just to make sure it's nothing in PHP. Try placing your code on another server if you can to see if the mail sends (make a small program with the mail function). If it does, then its most likely your ISP.

Comment: I have tested it with another server and its successful.

Comment: Then surely its your server. Check with your admins, or check /var/log/mail

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can connect directly to SMTP:

```
$smtp = fsockopen("localhost", 25, $errno, $errstr, 15);
if(!$smtp) { 
    echo "failed";
}
else {
    stream_set_timeout($smtp, 0, 80000);
    fwrite($smtp, "HELO domainname.com\r\n");
    stream_set_blocking($smtp, 0);
    fwrite($smtp, "MAIL FROM:<".$from.">\r\n");
    fwrite($smtp, "RCPT TO:<$to>\r\n");
    fwrite($smtp, "DATA\r\n");
    fwrite($smtp, "Date: ".date("r")."\r\n");
    fwrite($smtp, "From: <".$from_address.">\r\n");
    fwrite($smtp, "Reply-to: $replyto\r\n");
    fwrite($smtp, "Subject: Test\r\n");
    fwrite($smtp, "To: $to\r\n");
    $outMsg .= "Whatever your email body is, then end it with a period on a new line\r\n.\r\n";
    $bitesWritten = fwrite($smtp, $outMsg);
    echo "Wrote $bitesWritten of " strlen($outMsg);
}
```

Comment: Hi Kyle, thanks for the heads up. Tried your code but i got this error unable to connect. Maybe something is really wrong with the web server.

Comment: By the way, I have found this out. Our mail server is on google. Web server is in the hosting company. Do i need to contact google on this matter too?