# PHP Mail function not sending, something wrong with code

Tags: php, email

im using  linux system

I have tried a test mail php script on my site, and it works with that script. But not mine for some reason. Does anyone see anything wrong?

```
        $title = "Confirmation Required";   
        $msg = "An email has been sent to you with a confirmation link and your password.  Once clicking the link you will be asked to change your password and you will be ready to start earning!.<br><center><h2>The email was sent to <strong>$email</strong>.</h2></center><center>Go Check Your Email And Confirm Your Account</center><br>";

    $to = $email;
    $subject = "Confirm New Account";
    $message = "<h2>Welcome</h2> <h4><a href='$siteUrl/confirm.php?key=$userId'> Click Here To Confirm Account </a></h4> Your login information.<br>Login: <strong>$email</strong> <br> Password: <strong>$userId</strong>";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP \r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'To: Member <$email>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From:  <' . $adminEmail. '>' . "\r\n";
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);


    } // all good  

    echo "Mail sent OK";

    }
```

This is my php.ini file

```
; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t;
sendmail_from = Contact@mysite.com
```

Comment: Are you live or working on your machine locally?

Comment: Check the repsonse value of the `mail()` function. Is it `true` or `false`?

Comment: Can you post all of your code? In what you posted above, no email is set for you to send to because the `$email` variable has not been set. I realize you probably left that code out, but I don't know for sure that you do have it set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, the mail server is broken. I had the issue before, it was working then suddenly it stopped working. Please check this: [PHP Mail just suddenly stop working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347454/php-mail-just-suddenly-stop-working)

Or, it could be your mail configuration setting is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line:

```
$headers .= 'To: Member <$email>' . "\r\n";
```

To this:

```
$headers .= 'To: Member <' . $email . '>' . "\r\n";
```